# CentOS tmpfs mount doubling up?

Tags: centos, centos5, ramdisk

Everytime I mount a ramdisk with the following command, I get two instead of one ramdisk?

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=1024M tmpfs /home/site/public_html/var/cache
```

Mount shows no ramdisks mounted prior, and after running the command it shows:

```
tmpfs on /home/site/public_html/var/cache type tmpfs (rw,size=1024M)
tmpfs on /home/site/public_html/var/cache type tmpfs (rw,size=1024M)
```

If I unmount, both disappear, and when remounting, both appear.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have a bind mount in your home directory.

Type this:

```
mount | grep bind
```

You can also check the contents of /etc/mtab, though I doubt you will see duplicate entries there.